# 1-form with negative g-norm on surface

Tags: differential-geometry

On a surface if I have a metric $g={\omega_1}^2+{\omega_2}^2$ can I consider $\omega_1$ as a 1-form with g-norm $\pm$ 1?
I mean something like Minkowski norm so ${\omega_1}^2$ can be also negative?

Comment: Unless you complexify and work with complex-valued forms, you're going to need to put a negative sign in the formula for the metric. $\omega_1^2 = \omega_1\otimes\omega_1$ will stay positive.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin - Thank you for the answer, then my only possibility is write $g=-\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2$  ?

Comment: Is not possible something like $\eta(\omega_1, \omega_1) = - \omega_1^2 $?

Comment: and if I complexify, then do I work with real analytic surface with complex-value?
This is not a complex surface, only complex-value, am I right? then the metric construction is the same as for Euclidean case

Comment: I'm talking about allowing complex coefficients on your differential forms, not complexifying the surface itself. I have no idea what your $\eta$ (a few lines up) is supposed to mean. The metric tensor is a symmetric 2-tensor, and diagonalizing means you get a sum of (tensor) squares, as I already said.

Comment: But the base vector field (dual of 1-form $\omega$) it will be complex too, or not?

Comment: Yup. I don't know why you want to work with a sum of positive squares when you have an indefinite metric.

Comment: Because I don't know the metric, I set the calculation as if it was a Riemannian metric ($g=\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2$) but I found indefinite metric (i.e. $\omega_1^2$ negative)

Comment: Then despite after calculation I found $\omega_1^2$ negative though I supposed $g=\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2$  can I work supposing that g was $g=- \omega_1^2+\omega_2^2$ ?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know the metric? Maybe you should post more details about your actual situation.

Comment: I have to get the metric from a system of pde, and I worked with 1-forms, and I found imaginary $\omega_1$ (i.e. $\omega_1=f^{-3/2}(-3)^{1/2}= \pm j 3^{1/2}f^{-3/2}$), then $\omega_1^2=-3f^{-3}$ is negative because I must worked with positive $u$.

Comment: what does it means? is my surface real analytic with complex-value?